# Android App crashes after updating Android support library

Tags: android, crash, android-appcompat, runtimeexception

After updating my app is crashing while starting with the following stacktrace:

```
02-12 14:01:26.158: W/System(8631): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.ib-2/lib/arm
02-12 14:01:26.222: D/AndroidRuntime(8631): Shutting down VM
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312): Process: com.example.ib, PID: 7312
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field View_theme of type I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable' appears in /data/app/com.example.ib-1/base.apk)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.themifyContext(AppCompatViewInflater.java:229)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:84)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:938)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:992)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3909)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3981)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1969)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:149)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:60)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at com.example.ib.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
02-12 13:36:30.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I have copied appcompat jar files to the imported appcompat project, still, it doesn't work. Please help

Comment: Did you add the resources folder? Time to switch to Android Studio

Comment: it has resources folders with all necessary inside, my app was working before, it just suddenly crashed after update. I am not only doing android stuff in my workspace, does ide really matter?

Comment: Did you use the right api to compile? Using support v23 you have to compile with api 23.

Comment: my support library is v23.1.1 and I am compiling projects with api 23, as u said

Comment: Switching to Android Studio is the best advice IMO - Google ended all support for Eclipse last year, so these problems are only going to become more frequent (and the number of people who can resolve these issues will also shrink over time).

Comment: btw sdk tools version is v24.4.1, can it be the problem?